# NSMutableArray in appdelegate - EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to use a global array in the appdelegate as a quick fix for a demo I'm building. The relevant code for this

.h file has the declaration

> {
> NSMutableArray *trnEntered;
> }
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *trnEntered

.m file has the following code -

> trnEntered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
> NSLog(@"%@",[trnEntered count]); // prints null.
> [trnEntered addObject:@"1"]; 
> NSLog(@"%@",[trnEntered count]); // exec bad access.

Not sure where I'm going wrong here. Looks fairly straight forward.

Thanks for the help in advance,

Teja.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with your code:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[trnEntered count]); // prints null.
[trnEntered addObject:@"1"]; 
NSLog(@"%@",[trnEntered count]); // exec bad access.
```

Both calls to NSLog are trying to print an `NSUInteger` as an Objective-C object. This is going to cause a problem.  You should use `NSLog(@"%d", [trnEntered count]);`

I would suggest that you read more on [format specifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf), there is a lot of useful information.

As a little more information: the second `NSlog` is trying to print the `description` of the NSObject that the code claims is located at memory location 0x00000001.

Comment: Agh, I knew it was something like this, I can't believe I wasted 2 hours on this. thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome. I too have spent too much time on easy problems :)

Answer (score 0):

The first NSLog should not print 'null', you have a problem with the way you init.Try this instead.

```
trnEntered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
trnEntered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@",[trnEntered count]); // prints null.
[trnEntered addObject:@"1"];
NSLog(@"%@",[trnEntered count]); // exec bad access.
```

The reason is because you're using the formatter string wrong. You're trying to use an integer as a string pointer, which will of course lead to a segmentation fault (or EXC_BAD_ACCESS in apple terms). Use %d to print an integer, which is what [trnEntered count] returns.

Answer (score 0):

`NSLog` print ans in String format by default, so if you want to print integer value then you have to use `%d` and its value.